# Spring Cloud Stream flow as one application

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

As far as I know there is an option to use couple components of Spring Cloud Stream as one application by using `AggregateApplication` or `AggregateApplicationBuilder`.

From what I understood, spring will not use broker (Rabbit or Kafka) for communication between steps in this situation it will just pass result from previous step as an argument to the next almost directly, am I right?

If I am, is there another way to have running more components in one instance of an application with usage of a broker? I'm aware that this is not an architecture which is great for Cloud Stream, but now I don't have an infrastructure in which I can run Dataflow and also I would like to use durability of a brokers.

Answer (score 0):

In general, aggregation has been designed as a replacement for communication over a message broker - to reduce the latency by avoiding to go over a hop. That being said, it may make sense to add an option of have the channels bound for use cases like yours. Can you open a feature request in GitHub, please?